# How to construct boost spsc_queue with runtime size parameter to exchange cv::Mat objects between two processes using shared memory?

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, shared-memory

Trying to implement a produced consumer scenario where one process feeds [cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) objects into a queue buffer. And the consumer consumes them. [cv::Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) has a [settable allocator](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a536a771cbad0b8360091e0315ebfc524) that can be implemented for custom memory management, but I had no success in making it work. Popping from the que on consumer side led to segfaults. The closest I've got is [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/aleksas/64521cec1b5fa05477a47f46ad62f8b5) whwre cv::Mat is serialized and deserialized. Another downside of this implementation is buffer size is defined during compilation. So to reiterate the questions: how to efficiently implement cv::Mat lockfree queue in a shared memory.

Related questions:

- [unable to construct runtime boost spsc_queue with runtime size parameter in shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026590/unable-to-construct-runtime-boost-spsc-queue-with-runtime-size-parameter-in-shar/47032182?noredirect=1#comment114736038_47032182)
- [Shared-memory IPC synchronization (lock-free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595#22209595)
- [Boost shared memory and synchronized queue issue/crash in consumer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509815/boost-shared-memory-and-synchronized-queue-issue-crash-in-consumer-process/26514495#26514495)

Comment: I think the [linked implementation](https://gist.github.com/aleksas/64521cec1b5fa05477a47f46ad62f8b5) looks solid. Also, consider very critically whether you need lcckfree::queue vs lockfree::spsc_queue. It's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot due to additional restrictions on the thread use w.r.t. spsc_queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "settable" allocator for `cv::Mat` is NOT a Boost Interprocess allocator.

It looks like it's gonna be "hard" to implement [the `cv::Matallocator` interface](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d4c/classcv_1_1MatAllocator.html#details) to wrap one, as well.

> This could be because the fancier allocators are intended for CUDA support, but I'm guessing a bit here.

So, I'd strongly suggest serializing. This should be okay unless you're dealing with giant matrices. See e.g.

- [Serialization of cv::Mat giving strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062497/serialization-of-cvmat-giving-strange-result/32067313#32067313)

Of course you can serialize to shared memory: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html or https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/iostreams/doc/quick_reference.html#devices

Now if you need large matrices (and they NEED to be OpenCV anyways) consider using existing CV allocators to allocate from an *already existing* contiguous buffer in your shared memory.

This could be as simple as just a `vector<int8_t, bip::allocator<int8_t> >` or, indeed `array<int8_t, 4096>` constructed inside shared memory (either managed (`managed_shared_memory`) or unmanaged (`bip::mapped_region` that works on top of `bip::shared_memory_object`).

Comment: Thanks. My attepmt to implement as you've suggested: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f88180893581729b). For starters simple strings instead of cv::Mat. Changed to lockfree::queue and vectors instead of base_string. Does not compile yet though. :)

Comment: @alex I hadn't used `lockfree::queue` before, but looking at the requirements shows it requires trivial assignment and destructor: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html. Vectors don't have that.

Comment: Next step: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) uncovers that `lockfree::queue` doesn't support [allocators with fancy pointers](https://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/fancy-pointers.html). That just rules out BIP allocators, completely. (Oh by the way, I use [camomilla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dUZn3eloWE) to parse [those errors](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hCdjZGfxb4/))

Comment: The docs state [otehrwise](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/lockfree.html#lockfree.introduction___motivation.data_structure_configuration). However, I can only make that tick for compile-time capacity (which is meh because it really doesn't want to allocate anyways). Here's what I got: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eebc45fb1f5c48cc

Comment: Hmm, not just queue size but also vec size now is fixed at compile-time :( . Without that extra capacity restriction queue would be an ease choice over spsc_queue.